# Java json parsing exception

Tags: java, json

I'm trying to run this example I found on the internet. When it gets to the following line it terminates with the following error. Error and sample-json.txt pasted below example code. Am I missing something obvious?

```
JSONObject json = (JSONObject) JSONSerializer.toJSON( jsonTxt );
```

Imports:

```
package com.discursive.answers;

import java.io.InputStream;

import net.sf.json.JSONObject;
import net.sf.json.JSONSerializer;

import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;  
public class JsonParsing {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    InputStream is =    JsonParsing.class.getResourceAsStream( "sample-json.txt");
    String jsonTxt = IOUtils.toString( is );

    JSONObject json = (JSONObject) JSONSerializer.toJSON( jsonTxt );        
    double coolness = json.getDouble( "coolness" );
    int altitude = json.getInt( "altitude" );
    JSONObject pilot = json.getJSONObject("pilot");
    String firstName = pilot.getString("firstName");
    String lastName = pilot.getString("lastName");

    System.out.println( "Coolness: " + coolness );
    System.out.println( "Altitude: " + altitude );
    System.out.println( "Pilot: " + lastName );
    }
}


Error:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/lang/exception/NestableRuntimeException
Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:59138', transport: 'socket'
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
st java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
at com.discursive.answers.JsonParsing.main(JsonParsing.java:28)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.lang.exception.NestableRuntimeException
```

Here is the sample-json.txt file that is opened.

```
{'foo':'bar',
 'coolness':2.0,
 'altitude':39000,
 'pilot':{'firstName':'Buzz',
          'lastName':'Aldrin'},
 'mission':'apollo 11'}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep, it's definitely a classpath issue.  You can compile your project without third-party libraries existing, but you cannot run it without those libraries on your classpath.

I have copied your code to my local system and verified that I receive the same (initial) Exception that you get.  After grabbing the `commons-lang-2.6.jar` file and putting it on my classpath, I'm now receiving the following exception:

```
$ java com.so.Q8187623
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory
at net.sf.json.AbstractJSON.<clinit>(AbstractJSON.java:53)
at net.sf.json.util.CycleDetectionStrategy.<clinit>(CycleDetectionStrategy.java:36)
at net.sf.json.JsonConfig.<clinit>(JsonConfig.java:65)
at net.sf.json.JSONSerializer.toJSON(JSONSerializer.java:84)
at com.so.Q8187623.main(Q8187623.java:15)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
... 5 more
```

So just follow your way down the rabbit-hole adding classes to your classpath...

Comment: I was under the impression I could put my jar file in /System/Library/Java/Extensions on mac osx lion. Is this correct? I've done this with my lang jar file and i'm still getting the same error.

Comment: Try putting it in `/Users/yourname/Library/Java/lib` on OSX.

Comment: I was trying to use: commons-lang3-3.1.jar, i switch to commons-lang-2.6.jar and it now works fine.

Comment: There was a namespace change in the Apache Commons Lang v3 such that all classes are now in the `org.apache.commons.lang3` package-space.  Anything that is just `org.apache.commons.lang` is going to be v2 or prior.

Answer (score 0):

The *immediate* error looks like it's because you're missing `commons-lang.jar` from your classpath. However, given that the class which can't be found is an exception, I strongly suspect that when you've fixed that error, you'll immediately get another one... in the form of a `NestedRuntimeException` being thrown.

Comment: @Green JSON lib requires commons-lang and other libraries. Check http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/.

Answer (score 0):

I bumped into the same issue. I was using commons-collections 3.2.2 with commons-lang 2.6.
The issue got resolved after downgrading commons-collection to 3.2.1.